# Start the text on different column from same point

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to create a sidebar everything went according to plan but the fontawesome icons are not aligned on same point and it feels weird to see it , tried varoius method but it worsen it so here to get some help.

Plz open the code snippet at full page to see the issue of the disorder of fontawesome icon on each column.

```css
.side_bar {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: width 0.2s linear;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 310px;
}

.side_bar ul {
    list-style: none;
    
    display: table;
}

.side_bar li {
    padding: 1rem;
    
    width: 300px;
    display: table;
}

.side_bar i {
    padding-right: 1rem;

}

.side_bar li span {
    margin-left: 0.7rem;
}



li:has(div.down) {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    transition: height 1s linear;
}

.down {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 4rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    border-left: 3px solid rgb(195, 190, 190);
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    position: absolute;
}

.down>p {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    color: grey;
}

li:has(div.down):hover {
    height: var(--prog);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="side_bar">
        <ul>
            <li style="--prog: 180px;">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-chart-line"></i>
                <span>Promotion</span>
                 <div class="down">
                    <p>Add funds</p>
                    <p>Your sites</p>
                    <p>Statistics</p>
                    <p>Paid e-mail</p>
                 </div>
            </li>
            <li style="--prog: 340px;">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-sack-dollar"></i>
                <span>Earning</span>
                <div class="down">
                    <p>Surfing</p>
                    <p>Social tasks</p>
                    <p>VIP tasks</p>
                    <p>Mailbox</p>
                    <p>Referals</p>
                    <p>Withdraw funds</p>
                    <p>Blocked sites</p>
                    <p>Statistics</p>
                    <p>Execution history</p>
                 </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa-regular fa-user"></i>
                <span>Account</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bullhorn"></i>
                <span>News</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-question"></i>
                <span>Help</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                <span>Partnership</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa-regular fa-file"></i>
                <span>Offer</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-headset"></i>
                <span>Helpdesk</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: anyone who can solve it plz answer?

Comment: Can you describe in text what is wrong with the alignment? Or maybe add an image containing "actual vs desired".

Comment: @PeterB expand the snippet you will see Partnership and dollar font isnt aligned with the above others text and icon its the problem hope you get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `i` element's layout to `table-cell` and give it a fixed width with alignment set to `center`:

```css
.side_bar {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.2s linear;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 310px;
}

.side_bar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
}

.side_bar li {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 300px;
  display: table;
}

.side_bar i {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.side_bar li span {
  margin-left: 0.7rem;
}

li:has(div.down) {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 1s linear;
}

.down {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 4rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border-left: 3px solid rgb(195, 190, 190);
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.down>p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: grey;
}

li:has(div.down):hover {
  height: var(--prog);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="side_bar">
  <ul>
    <li style="--prog: 180px">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-chart-line"></i>
      <span>Promotion</span>
      <div class="down">
        <p>Add funds</p>
        <p>Your sites</p>
        <p>Statistics</p>
        <p>Paid e-mail</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li style="--prog: 340px">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-sack-dollar"></i>
      <span>Earning</span>
      <div class="down">
        <p>Surfing</p>
        <p>Social tasks</p>
        <p>VIP tasks</p>
        <p>Mailbox</p>
        <p>Referals</p>
        <p>Withdraw funds</p>
        <p>Blocked sites</p>
        <p>Statistics</p>
        <p>Execution history</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa-regular fa-user"></i>
      <span>Account</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bullhorn"></i>
      <span>News</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-question"></i>
      <span>Help</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
      <span>Partnership</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa-regular fa-file"></i>
      <span>Offer</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-headset"></i>
      <span>Helpdesk</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: damn i tried giving the display table but didnt work out ,can you explain me something more abt how does this work so it will help me in my future

Comment: hey bro you on??

Comment: The reason why the icons are not aligned when placed on the left is because they have varying widths. By default, icons are aligned to the left (`text-align: left`), which means they will not be aligned on the same point. To correct this, we give them the same width and align them to the center point. This ensures that they appear aligned correctly.